# python automatic (or dynamic) import classes in packages

Tags: python

I'm writing some kind of automated test suite and I want to make sure the classes contained in the package 'tests' get imported automatically upon runtime in the main namespace, without adding them to the `__init__` file of the package.

So here is the script I have so far:

```
import os

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('tests'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.lower().endswith(('.pyc', '__init__.py')): continue

        module = ".".join([dirpath, filename.split('.')[0]])

        print module
```

If I use `modulename = __import__(module)` the classes get added to the module 'modulename' and not the main namespace.

My question is, how do I import them to the current namespace?

So I can do things like:

```
testcase = TestCase()
testcase.run()
results = testcase.results()
```

or whatever in the main script without explicitly importing the classes.

Thanks in advance!

Thank you all for replying and trying to help me out.

Comment: Why aren't you using Python's unittest testloader capabilities?

Comment: It might be relevant if you are using Python 2 or 3.

Comment: @S.Lott: Unfortunately, `unittest` does silly things like import `__main__.py` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get classes from some module, there can be better way but here is generic way to get you started

```
mod = __import__("mod")
for klass in vars(mod):
    o =  getattr(mod, klass)
    if type(o) == type:
        print o
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I exactly understand your question, but you might try [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/) to [discover](http://www.somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.1/finding_tests.html) your test suites.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the exec on a formatted string for each module name in your scanned directory:

```
exec "from %s import *" % moduleName
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in __init__.py of the tests package and it will import all tests in the current package and subpackages.

```
import pkgutil
import unittest

for loader, module_name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
    module = loader.find_module(module_name).load_module(module_name)
    for name in dir(module):
        obj = getattr(module, name)
        if isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, unittest.case.TestCase):
            exec ('%s = obj' % obj.__name__)
```

As others have said, if you're trying to have all of your tests discovered, there are better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `__import__` and assign it to a variable like this

```
modulename = __import__(module)
```

Use `importlib.import_module` instead, and don't assign it:

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module(module)
```

At least on Python 3.4, this works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I do not fully understand the need because you can collect all the modules and iterate thru test case classes

but if you do want to get all names in current scope
use something like

```
execfile("mod.py")
```

it will get all classed defined in mod.py into scope

Comment: How can I iterate trough the test case classes? I don't know how to do that. I guess that's what I'm looking for?

Comment: I have put a sample in another answer, as i can't put code in comment